# Efficient subqueries in Hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have table-

```
Employee    Dept    Visited
1   a   yes
1       yes
1       yes
2   b
1   b   yes
2       yes
3   ab
4   ac  yes
5       yes
5       yes
6   fe
6   
7   ad  yes
2   ad  yes
3   a   yes
3   c
6       yes
7   
8   a   yes
8       yes
9   fe  yes
```

*

> I need to find all employee who Do not have Null values for 2 Depts with
>   visited = yes

*

I tried to write the query in Hive and following -

```
select c.Employee 
from table c
where c.Employee NOT IN (select d.Employee from table d where Visited = 'Yes' and Dept = '' group by d.Employee having count(d.Employee) >=2)
;
```

It works but this query takes load of time so I believe it can be better.
Any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `having` and `group by`:

```
select c.Employee
from table c
group by c.Employee
having sum(case when c.dept is null and c.visited = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) < 2;
```

Comment: thanks for the query but I missed a crucial point in the question which I updated, its actually to find the users who did not have Null values for the condition mentioned

Comment: @ABC . . . That is actually a relatively small change to the query -- removing the `where` and modifying the `having`.